# Как получить nodejs express картинку со стороны клиента?

Tags: javascript, node.js

На клиенте выбираю картинку.
По кнопке sub картинку запросом fetch отправляю на сервер.
А на сервере не получается ее нормально получить.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("script");


        function onImageChange(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            console.log('reader', reader);

            var img1 = document.getElementById('imgId');
            console.log('img1 = ', img1);
            var file = document.getElementById("inputId").files[0];
            console.log('file = ', file);

            reader.onloadend = function(){
                console.log('img1.src', img1.src);
                img1.src = reader.result;
            }

            if (file) {
                console.log('reader.readAsDataURL(file) = ', reader.readAsDataURL(file));
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                img1.src = "";
            }
        }

        function sub(){
            var img1 = document.getElementById('imgId');
            console.log('fetch');
            var img2 = img1.src;
            console.log('img2 = ', img2);
            fetch('/', {method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}, body: img2})
            .then(res => console.log(res));
        };
    </script>

    <img id="imgId" src="" alt="...">
    <input id="inputId" type="file" onchange="onImageChange()">
    <input id="subId" type="submit" name="" value="sub" onclick="sub()">

</body>
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.post('/', function(req, res){    
   console.log(req.originalUrl);
   console.log("req", req.query);
});

app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("test 4000"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doigrales: 
в результате минимальный код заработал в таком виде.
index.html:

```
<form class="classCard" action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="nameCard" id="cardId">
        <input id="inputId" type="file" name="avatar">
        <input id="subId" type="submit" name="subCard" value="sub">
</form>
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    //Надо еще добавить проверку на является ли файл картинкой.
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, __dirname + '/savePic') //Здесь указывается путь для сохранения файлов
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/', upload.any(), function(req, res){
    console.log("req = ", req.files);
    res.send(req.files);
});

app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("test 4000"))
```

Comment: я рад, что мой ответ был полезен и проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Такой способ не совсем актуален, но Вас я думаю удовлетворит. Для сервера:

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.post('/', (request, responce) => {

        let body = '';

        request.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        request.on('end', function () {

            let parseBody = body.split(/^path:([а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9-_-]+[\/])([а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9-_-]+\.\w+);/);                                                            

            let imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(parseBody[3]);

            fs.mkdir('./Images/'+ parseBody[1], function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Failed to create directory', err);
                }
            });

            fs.writeFile('./Images/'+ parseBody[1] + parseBody[2], imageBuffer.data, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error writing file', err);
                    response.write("Error writing file\n");
                    response.end();
                } else {
                    console.log('Writing file succeded');
                    response.write("Writing file succeded\n");
                    response.end();
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {    

        const matches = dataString.match(/^data:(\w+[\/](\w+));base64,(.+)$/); 

        if (!matches || matches.length !== 4) {
            return new Error('Invalid input string');
        }

        return {
            type : matches[1],
            format : matches[2],
            data : new Buffer(matches[3], 'base64')
        };
    }
```

Предлагаю ознакомиться с отправкой файлов с помощью FormData:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Как на стороне сервера принимать файлы:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

**Обновлено:**

Используйте заголовок 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

На сервере:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, __dirname) //Здесь указывается путь для сохранения файлов
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/', upload.fields([{ name: 'picture', maxCount: 10 }]), 
    (req, res) => { 
        res.status(200).send({uploaded: true}); 
    }
);
```

Comment: на клиенте добавил - var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('picture', img2, 'test.jpeg'); fetch('/', {method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg;base64"}, body: formData})   .

Comment: на сервере - const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    console.log("req = ", req.body);
    res.send('res end');
});  .  Результат тот же. Выдает в боди пустой объект.

Comment: @ncux199rus ответ обновил